# UNION of two queries using a subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to have something like:

```
SELECT MAX(id), somefield
UNION ALL
SELECT MIN(id), someotherfield
FROM
(SOME GIANT SQL JOIN)
```

Basically, I want to use the same join subquery in the two UNIONed queries.

Comment: Sorry: the syntax is basically: `query1 union query2` (so: both subqueries each need a `FROM ...` ) And: union is almost always an indication of bad design.

Comment: Well, the uses of UNION you have in your mind might be bad design. It's almost always incorrect to assume bad design when the use-case is not known. And the answer below works.

Comment: You are correct: I don't know the `use-case` But How could I know, you did not show it... BTW: a syntactically incorrect snippet in your question wont help you.

Comment: Yes. Syntax wasn't the point of the snippet. I received the help I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: `Syntax wasn't the point of the snippet.` I am going to make sticker with that text on it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the with clause, in this manner:

```
with sub as
 (some giant sql join)
select max(id), somefield
  from sub
 group by somefield
union all
select min(id), someotherfield from sub group by someotherfield
```

(as an alternative to writing out the same inline view twice)